# Translate batch file into Python where an exe should be run with its parameters

Tags: python, loops, batch-file, for-loop, translate

I have this code in a batch file:

```
D:\Programmes\POISSON\PoissonRecon.x64\PoissonRecon.exe --in D:\Programmes\POISSON\fichier1_test.ply --color 16 --depth 10 --out fichier1_test_poisson.ply --density --samplesPerNode 1.50 --fullDepth 5 --pointWeight 4 --bType 2
```

First of all, I'd like to "translate" it in Python.

However, this is a simple case for 1 file (which path is written in the code as "--in").

So in a second time, I'd like to write the same Python code but not only for one file, but for every .ply files located in a specific folder. (It would be great if, when the python script is executed, if it could ask me the path of the folder where all the .ply files are located.)

I guess a for loop should be used? And also variables?

I have the level 0 in Python... so any idea would be really appreciated :)

I have tried this code but it doesn't work :/

```
import subprocess, os

s = r'D:\Programmes\POISSON\PoissonRecon.x64\PoissonRecon.exe'

subprocess.Popen(["s", "--in D:\Programmes\POISSON\fichier1_test.ply", "--color 16", "--depth 9", "--out fichier1_test_poisson.ply", "--density", "--samplesPerNode 1.50", "--fullDepth 5", "--pointWeight 4", "--bType 2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Each command line argument needs its own string, like so:

```
import subprocess, os

s = r'D:\Programmes\POISSON\PoissonRecon.x64\PoissonRecon.exe'

subprocess.Popen(
    [
        s,
        "--in", "D:\Programmes\POISSON\fichier1_test.ply",
        "--color", "16",
        "--depth", "9",
        "--out", "fichier1_test_poisson.ply",
        "--density",
        "--samplesPerNode", "1.50",
        "--fullDepth", "5",
        "--pointWeight", "4",
        "--bType", "2"
    ]
)
```

Comment: You forgot a rather important part: Actually passing the command string as the variable `s`, not a string containing the letter s, `"s"`.

Comment: Thanks, overlooked :)